# Running NodeJS server and Angular client server from a desktop shortcut

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, server, mean-stack

I have a NodeJS server that I run using `npm start`and an AngularJS client UI application that I also run using `npm start`, is there a way to create a desktop shortcut to run the command lines with just a click?

Comment: Easiest way is probably to write a batch/shell script.

Comment: I'm looking for that, the problem is both commands requires a new cmd line window ( both are npm start) so I don't know what arguments to add

Comment: For linux this question and the first answer cover it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/299052/how-to-execute-sh-script-from-a-desktop-shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, a batch script seems like the easiest way of doing this. If you're on Windows, this should do what you need:

```
start cmd /k "cd C:/yournodeproject && npm start"
start cmd /k "cd C:/yourangularproject && npm start"
```

- `start` runs a command in a new window.
- `cmd /k` allows us to pass a string into the new command line.
- Each window switches to the relevant directory and runs `npm start`.

Unfortunately I don't know enough about Bash to offer a Linux equivalent, but hopefully this will get you started.